# React State not updating but can log the results

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api

Working with the YouTube API to first search for videos by keyword, and then complete a second call to obtain the video statistics to be able to filter out by view count.

**Problem**

I can successfully console log out the ID's returned in the first API call `youtube.get` for videos in state. Then if videos are returned, it pulls out the video id's to update the state again. Next, I send another API call `views.api` to collect video statistics that I want to use for filtering by view count since the youtube API does not return this in one call *(unless I missed how to do this and am overusing the API unnecessarily)*.

`console.log(videoStats.data.items);` returns the proper statistics for the specific ID in the API call, however it is not updating the state and I have an empty array with `console.log(this.state.videoStatistics);`

I've tried with and without the spread operator but it does not update with either. Fairly new to react so I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing to get this to update correctly. Additionally, how could I restructure this to be more efficient instead of the repeating if statements?

**Process I am looking for**

1. query search with youtube /search API
2. extract video id's from the results
3. another API call to /videos for the statistics
4. filter by a user input view count
5. returned videos that are a match the view count filter
6. any videos that don't match are dropped and the next video is pulled

**Below is my submit method**

```
handleSubmit = async (searchQuery) => {
        const results = await youtube.get('/search', {
            params: {
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 4,
                key: KEY,
                q: searchQuery,
                type: 'video',
            },
        });
        this.setState({
            videos: results.data.items,
        });

        if (this.state.videos) {
            const videoList = [...this.state.videos];

            videoList.map((video) => {
                let id = video.id.videoId;
                this.setState({
                    videoIds: [...this.state.videoIds, id],
                });
            });
        }

        if (this.state.videoIds) {
            let vidid = [...this.state.videoIds];

            vidid.map(async (id) => {
                const videoStats = await views.get('/videos', {
                    params: {
                        part: 'statistics',
                        maxResults: 4,
                        key: KEY,
                        id: id,
                    },
                });
                console.log(videoStats.data.items);
                this.setState({
                    videoStatistics: [...videoStats.data.items],
                });
            });
            console.log(this.state.videoStatistics);
        }
    };
```

Comment: State update is asynchronous...Your code immediately tries to access state after setting it...The updated value in the state would not be available at such time...You would want to provide a callback as second argument to the setState call and move the logic that depends on the value of this.state.videos to that callback...something along the lines of ...
`this.setState({ videos: results.data.item }, () => { code that depends on the value in state});`

Comment: My state updates with the videos fine, it's when I make the second API call to get the video statistics. I log ```videoStats.data.items``` and it returns the data I am looking for, but that doesn't get pushed into state with spread operator as it does in the previous map function. 

```console.log(videoStats.data.items);
                this.setState({
                    videoStatistics: [...videoStats.data.items],
                });```

Comment: Just noticed this, won't the below line of code overwrite statistics in the state?
`this.setState({
                    videoStatistics: [...videoStats.data.items],
 });`